# Misunderstood timezone conversion

Tags: python, timezone

I'm converting a datetime into another timezone (from Europe/Paris to America/Guadeloupe). But result is not what I expect:

```
import pytz
import datetime

tzinfo = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')
datetime_with_timezone = datetime.datetime(
    2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzinfo
)

print(datetime_with_timezone)
new_tzinfo = pytz.timezone('America/Guadeloupe')
print(datetime_with_timezone.astimezone(new_tzinfo))
```

Produces:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00+00:09
1999-12-31 19:51:00-04:00
```

Why does `datetime_with_timezone` contain `+00:09` ?

Comment: And oddly you got `19:51:00` on the second time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue, as according to the [pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic):

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.

The documentation provides further advice that

> The preferred way of dealing with times is to always work in UTC, converting to localtime only when generating output to be read by humans.